# Converting remote RRD to JSON format

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rrdtool, rrd

I have a project wherein I need to access remotely hosted RRD files and create a highly interactive dashboard to visualize the data (most likely using Rails/Flot etc..)

I've looked into projects such as RRDTool and Jarmon (which seems to be collectd specific) and was wondering if there was a proven way to get the data from the rrd files into a format I can use on the javascript side of things. I intend to have this running on a fairly simple heroku instance, if that's any indicator of my server restrictions.

Thanks so much,
Nader

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at rrdtool xport called on the command line it can produce json for you or when called via a scripting api you get the raw data which you cann then easily convert to json using your scripting language.

HTH
tobi

Comment: Is this json output can use in Flot graphs?

Answer (score 0):

You need JavascriptRRD:

http://javascriptrrd.sourceforge.net/index.html

As the name implies (Javascript RRD), javascriptRRD is a javascript library for reading and interpreting RRD (Round Robind Database) files from both remote Web servers and local file directories. It uses AJAX-like techniques, but without any code being run on a remote Web server; i.e. it provides a purely client-side access to RRD files.

The javascriptRRD package provides the basic RRD reading libraries, as well as helper libraries to make displaying of RRD files easy with the Flot library.